# TeXStudio: Any command is an "Undefined control sequence"

Tags: errors, miktex, compiling, texstudio

I'm trying to configure TeXStudio (using Windows) with MiKTeX. I configured the path to `latex.exe` and `pdflatex.exe` in Options\Commands and still I get errors compiling any `.tex`.

Every command (like `\title`, `\usepackage`, `\begin`) produces an error: "Undefined control sequence".

[image: Commands]

[image: Build]

[image: Result]

Comment: Please provide a snapshot of your setting or MWE of what you are compiling.

Comment: Hello @azetina I've updated my original post. Please note that the \bin\ folder is already in my path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image shows the `pdflatex` command is set up to use pdftex.exe (plain tex) not pdflatex.exe (latex) so latex commands are not defined.